# How to chain queries with rxjava and room

Tags: java, android, rx-java, android-room

I need to fill the fields of an object in order to post it to an API.

I am using rxjava and room but my chain of orders is failling

My daos

```
    @Dao
abstract public class PokemonDao implements BaseDao<Pokemon>{
    @Query("SELECT * FROM pokemons ORDER BY id ASC")
    abstract public Flowable<List<Pokemon>> getAll();
}

    @Dao
abstract public class NoteDao implements BaseDao<Note>{


    @Query("SELECT * FROM notes WHERE idPokemon = :idPokemon ORDER BY registerDate DESC")
    abstract public Flowable<List<Note>> getNotes(int idPokemon);
}
```

I need to create an object that has the data of the pokemon with a list of notes associated

I did the following on my viewmodel

```
            pokemonRepository.getFavourites()
                    .toObservable()
                .flatMap(new Function<List<Pokemon>, ObservableSource<?>>() {
                    @Override
                    public ObservableSource<?> apply(List<Pokemon> favourites) throws Exception {
                        return Observable.fromIterable(favourites);
                    }
                })
    .flatMap(new Function<Object, ObservableSource<?>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<?> apply(Object o) throws Exception {
                    return getNotesObservable((Favourite) o);
                }
            })
    .toList()
.toObservable()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

                    .subscribeWith(new SingleObserver<List<Object>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(List<Object> objects) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }
            })
```

I also use this method

```
private Observable<Object> getNotesObservable(Pokemon favourite) {


    Observable<Object> lolo = noteRepository.getNotes(Integer.parseInt(favourite.getId()))
            .map(new Function<List<Note>, Object>() {
                @Override
                public Favourite apply(List<Note> notes) throws Exception {
                    favourite.notesList= notes;
                    return favourite;
                }
            })
            .toObservable();

    return lolo;

}
```

My problem is that on the subscribeWith onNext method is never called.
My goal it that when onNext is called it should have a list of pokemon and each pokemon should have their notes

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should try [one-to-many relations in Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#one-to-many). It seems it could give you what you want without such manipulation with data

Comment: I have two classes: Pokemon and note. So each pokemon can have a list of notes associated. I dont think I am having the "one-to-many relations in Room" you are suggesting @sergiytikhonov

Comment: I've just mentioned another way, that you could think about. For that way you need 3 classes - Pokemon (without list), Note, and PokemonWithList (with that it would be one-to-many relations). The latter class has to be plain class, not associated with SQLite. Details and examples are in documentation link above. But you can follow your way ) My personal opinion that to save list of values inside table's column isn't very clean, but it's a question of taste

Comment: Thanks @sergiytikhonov for the help. If I create the class PokemonWithList  I sill need to call 1 query to get all the pokemon and then call a query to get the notes for each pokemon I have. What I am trying to achieve is how to get all that information with Rxjava by chaining the queries. Because first Ineed to get the pokemons and the with each pokemon id get their notes

Comment: Added an answer, because to write it in comment too long. It's the same concept as in article I mentioned above but with your classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below I describe Room-ish way for your task without RxJava

Let's say you have these entities:

```
@Entity
public class Pokemon {
    @PrimaryKey public int id;
    public String name;
    // other fields
    ........
}

@Entity
public class Note {
    @PrimaryKey public int noteId;
    public int pokemonId;
    // other fields
    ........ 
}
```

Then you can add another class (it's just a class with no connection to SQLite):

```
public class PokemonWithNotes {
    @Embedded public Pokemon pokemon; // here you'll get your pokemon
    @Relation(
         parentColumn = "id",
         entityColumn = "pokemonId"
    )
    public List<Note> notesList; // here you'll het your notes' list
}
```

and add method to your dao:

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM Pokemon")
public List<PokemonWithNotes> getPokemonListWithNotes();
```

Room orders to this method to get both Pokemons and Notes and connect them (without two queries)

Using this method you'll get your List with Pokemons and notes.

Comment: Thanks man, I was approaching the problem in very incorrect way. Almost 3 days struggling with this. Thanks a lot @sergiytikhonov for your help.